при копировании сайта некоторые элементы не отображаются на странице хотя в коде они скопированы
Есть сайт https://a700cargo.ru/ , мне нужно его скопировать. Использовала программу cyotec webcopy, что-то скопировалось идеально что-то нет. Особенно все плохо с главной страницей
Что у меня получилось в итоге: http://artidevx.beget.tech/
Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему

Это что-то вроде, Вы, грубо говоря, украли сайт и нужно помочь Вам "починить"?)

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ===> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Скорее всего, нужный вам сайт, как и большинство коммерческих сайтов, работает на каком то фреймворке или CMS. В таком случае обработчик запросов может не выдавать медиафалы, даже стили, на запросы чего-то вроде cyotec webcopy.
Если хотите серьезно взять за основу какой-то сайт, то тут без ручного анализа не обойтись никак - открываете просмотр кода страницы в браузере и анализируете.
